# SQL - Merging two queries that have one column difference

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I have two SQL queries that gives me this kind of results :

```
Employee id | Week | SUM(Qty sold)
1             42     2
3             38     15


Employee id | Week | SUM(Qty bought)
1             42     5
2             35     10
3             42     6
```

When I do a full outer join, I get :

```
Employee id | Week | SUM(Qty sold) | Employee id | Week | SUM(Qty bought)
1             42     2                1             42     5
2             35     10               null          null   null
3             38     15               null          null   null
null          null   null             3             42     6
```

But what I'm trying to do but don't know how to is :

```
Employee id | Week | SUM(Qty sold) | SUM(Qty bought)
1             42     2               5            
2             35     null            10
3             38     15              null
3             42     null            6
```

The final goal would be to add another column with sold - bought.
My real tables are more complicated than that but I think it's easier to understand that way (and also I can't share them).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I've been plucking my hair all afternoon yesterday over this query.

Thanks

PS: I don't know if that changes anything, but I'm using teradata.

Comment: In that full outer join query of yours, add a column `COALESCE(left.employeeid, right.employeeid)`

Comment: Please post the query (a simplified one is OK).  Is your join on the `EmployeeId, Week` columns?  if so, the 3rd line in your output doesn't seem quite right -- `3             38     15               null          null   null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `COALESCE`. Try like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.EmployeeID, t2.EmployeeID)
    ,COALESCE(t1.Week,.t2.Week)
    ,SUM(Qty sold)
    ,SUM(Qty bought)
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.EmployeeID= t2.EmployeeID
```